# ROS Topics Data Communication over separate networks

Tags: communication, ros-melodic, rosbridge, network, rosmaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to send ROS Topic data from one ROS Master to another ROS Master. Both ROS Masters are on different networks.
There is a limitation in my project for which I am receiving some data through a different connection, and some data through another connection.
Now, I want to send all the data to just one ROS master where everything is happening.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/386229/ros-topics-data-communication-over-separate-networks/) by [Raza Rizvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/84361/raza-rizvi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2021-09-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-11**:
Are you talking about something like #q344294?

**Comment by [Raza Rizvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/84361/raza-rizvi/) on 2021-09-11**:
No. In that case, the network connection is the same. In my case, the separate machines have different network connections that belong to different pools.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-11**:
I believe you're going to have to provide more information for people to be able to help you. Right now it's unclear what you're trying to do exactly.

Perhaps include a concrete example of the flow of data you're envisioning.

As a quick note however:

> Now, I want to send all the data to just one ROS master where everything is happening.

There is nothing 'happening' in the ROS master. It's not involved in data exchange between nodes. It only helps setting up connections.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-14**:
In question #q223371 recommends: http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie

Have you considered this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve this problem by bridging two network adapters into one Virtual Machine.
One adapter was the Wireless Adapter of my laptop, and the second one was the ethernet adapter of my laptop.

After bridging the two separate adapters into one Virtual Machine and connecting the adapters to separate networks, I was able to get two IP Addresses in one machine and was able to communicate to two separate networks using these two IP Addresses.

---

Originally posted by [Raza Rizvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/84361/raza-rizvi/) with karma: 95 on 2021-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-29**:
Ingenious solution

**Comment by [Raza Rizvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/84361/raza-rizvi/) on 2021-09-29**:
Haha thanks, don't forget to vote for this solution.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-30**:
So in the end you just needed a multi-homed host? That doesn't require multiple NICs on most OS. You can assign multiple IPs to the same NIC.

**Comment by [Raza Rizvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/84361/raza-rizvi/) on 2021-09-30**:
No, I wanted to connect to two separate networks inside one PC. So for that, I used two separate network adapters and connected them to separate networks.
In doing so, and lunching one ROS Master, I was able to get all the ROS topics from both the separate networks, into just one ROS Master inside the PC.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-09-30**:
Unless they're physically separated networks, all you need is a router.

But if you're happy, we're happy.